# Hive throws an error while creating table "Cannot validate serde: com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe"

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hdfs

Working  on apache-hive-0.13.1. 
while creating table hive throw an error as below

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot validate serde: com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe
```

table structure is

```
create external table tweets(id BigInt, created_at String, scource String, favorited Boolean, retweet_count int, 
retweeted_status Struct < 
    text:String,user:Struct< 
        screen_name:String, name:String>>,
    entities Struct<
        urls:Array<Struct<          
             expanded_url:String>>,
        user_mentions:Array<Struct<
            screen_name:String,
            name:String>>,
        hashtags:Array<Struct<text:String>>>,

text String,
user Struct<
    screen_name:String,
    name:String,
    friends_count:int,
    followers_count:int,
     statuses_count:int,
    verified:boolean, 
    utc_offset:int,
    time_zone:String> , 
in_reply_to_screen_name String)
partitioned by (datehour int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
location '/home/edureka/sachinG'
```

Added a `json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` in class  to resolved the issue but no success

Comment: Usually this means the required jar is not available in the classpath, kindly refer (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins) to cross verify whether you have added the JAR correctly.

Comment: Thanks Manoj  for reply, I think  , I Added a json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar correctly As Hive give acknowledgement "Added /home/edureka/Desktop/LMS/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar to class path" .

Comment: Also when i checked the added jars with "list jars" commends it's show me the "json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

Comment: Where did you get the JAR from? if it is not from cloudera then the classpath might be different. Eg: org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe

Comment: off-course. I got it from internet

Answer (score 2):

Finally , got a solution for this. The issue is with `json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`
Different distribution (Cloudera, Azure, etc ) needed different JSON-Serde jar file. Means, serde jar should be compatible to there distribution.

I changed jar and it worked for me.

Comment: Hey where did you get the jar file from?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue while working with hive 1.2.1 and hbase 0.98. I followed below steps and the ***issue was resolved***.

1) Copied all the hbase-* files from hbase/lib location to hive/lib directory

2) Verified that the hive-hbase-handler-1.2.1.jar was present in hive/lib

3) Verified that hive-serde-1.2.1.jar was present in hive/lib

4) Verified that zookeeper-3.4.6.jar was present in hive/lib(If not copy from hbase/lib and paste to hive/lib)

5) In the hive-site.xml(If not present use hive-default.xml.template) located at hive/conf under 'both'

a) **hive.aux.jars.path** field and

b) **hive.added.jars.path** field

give path '/usr/local/hive/lib/'.

6) Open hive terminal and create the table using below command:-

```
CREATE TABLE emp_hive (
RowKey_HIVE String,
Employee_No int,
Employee_Name String,
Job String,
Mgr int,
Hiredate String,
Salary int,
Commision int,
Department_No int
)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" =":key,details:Employee_No_hbase,details:Employee_Name_hbase,details:job_hbase,details:Mgr_hbase,details:hiredate_hbase,details:salary_hbase,details:commision_hbase,details:department_no_hbase")
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name"="emp_hbase");
```